# CSS: float left doesn't float the elements next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I've encountered an issue which doesn't make sense.

basically, I' trying to float 2 divs next to each other and I used `float:left;` in their CSS property but they don't float next to each other.

This is a working [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gymzfg9r/1/)

**This is my CSS:**

```
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    background-image:url(images/platenav-bg.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    height:30px;
    width: 220px;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left:5px;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\02795';
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2796";
    color:#FFF;
}
div.panel {
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;  
}
```

**AND THIS IS MY HTML:**

```
<div style="width:100%;">   

<div id="accor" style="width:220px; margin-top:10px;">
 <button id="ureg" class="accordion">1 </button>
<div class="panel">

<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">2 </button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">BORDER</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>3 </p>
</div>

</div>



<div style="width:200px; margin-top:10px; float:left; background-color:#000; height:200px;">


</div>

</div>
```

Could someone please advise on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `float:left` to this id `#accor` this will solve your problem

```
#accor {
   float:left;
}
```